# Issue with entities relations (core data)

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

i have two entities named UserInfo and Department which having to-one and to-many relations respectively, on running my app im getting this..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Department in Department.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UserInfo in UserInfo.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Department in Department.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_UserInfo in UserInfo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

// Department.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class UserInfo;

@interface Department : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * post;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *user;
@end

@interface Department (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addUserObject:(UserInfo *)value;
- (void)removeUserObject:(UserInfo *)value;
- (void)addUser:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeUser:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

// Department.m

```
#import "Department.h"
#import "UserInfo.h"

@implementation Department

@dynamic id;
@dynamic post;
@dynamic user;

@end
```

what is going wrong?

Comment: could u show us the src of Department.h/m

Comment: Are you linked against the CoreData framework?

Comment: seems to be the problem with coredata framework linking. is it linked properly in ur app?

Comment: oh yes ..core data framework was missing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `CoreData.framework` from `BuildPhases->LinkBinaryWithLibrary->Add`  in your project.